# Monitor SSL Certificate Changes

Tags: ssl-certificate, monitoring

Is there a good tool to check when a certificate has been changed, in our environment we have certificates being changed by an operational team that is creating issues. I looked at NAGIOS check_ssl_certificate but it seems it only warns when a certificate is about to expire not if the certificate has changed.

Comment: What sort of issues? I'd fix the underlying problem - is the CA untrusted? Are they messing up the certificates? Are you pinning certs?

Comment: Basically the Ops team decides from time to time without warning to renew the certificate and we have clients and middleware that needs to accept that certificate. So we don't want to * all certificates, so we want to get alerted and import the certificate.

Comment: Why do they need to accept it, though? Can't *that* part be fixed, so ops can renew certs (a normal part of their job) without needing to worry about everything breaking unexpectedly?

Comment: don't understand your comment, the API gateway that is in the middle needs to accept the certificate so there is a trust between the identity provider and the API GW

Comment: You should trust the CA that issues the certificates, instead of trusting each certificate.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to monitor for "changes" you need to compare the current state to a previous state. I am not aware of any such tool out of the box, but you can relatively easily use the ubiquitous `openssl s_client` to connect to the server, dump the certificate, and compare to the previous one. E.g.

```
old_cert="$(cat "$store/$server:$port")"
new_cert="$(openssl s_client -showcerts $server:$port </dev/null)"
if echo "$new_cert" | grep -q "END CERTIFICATE"; then
    if [[ $old_cert != $new_cert ]]; then
        Raisenthenalaram
        echo "$new_cert" > "$store/$server:$port"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the template, indeed i did not find such tool, i guess i will build on using the openssl_client